# How do I move an AWS application instance from us-east-1d to us-east-1b?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have an instance that I accidentally setup on us-east-1d without realizing it. I have another application that is supposed to connect to it but times out. I contacted AWS support and they told me the reason why is because the connection isn't going through the load balancer which only works for us-east-1a and us-east-1b instances. Is there an easy way to move my instance from us-east-1d to either us-east-1a or us-east-1b?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Documentation is generally excellent and covers many common situations. In your case it's covered [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/).

> To move an EC2 instance, create a new Amazon Machine Image (AMI) in
>   the desired target Availability Zone, launch a new instance based on
>   this image, and then reassign the Elastic IP address from the instance
>   you are moving to the new image.

The linked article contains detailed step by step instructions. I see no value copying them into this answer, though SF usually prefers that, as AWS documentation is kept up to date.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I successfully launched a copy of my instance. However it's not showing up in my Elastic Beanstalk Applications. Also I can't seem to connect to it from my browser. I'll keep messing with it but do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. I had to change the security group. Thank you so much!